# Recommendation of financial mathematics books for beginner

Tags: finance

I am a PhD student in pure mathematics. 
However, I start to learn financial mathematics by myself and plan to apply one more PhD course in this major 2 years later.

Could you please recommend some text book for beginner?

Thank you for your consult and time.

Answer (score 1):

"Options, Futures and Other Derivatives" by John C. Hull might be a good choice if you don't have much prior knowledge to finance.

Comment: Do you know some online course relating to this major?

Comment: No, so far I haven't participated in any online courses on financial maths - just ordinary lectures at university.